# Implementing HeapSort in WL

Tags: sorting

Good day,

I am trying to implement the HeapSort Algorithm using WL. My attempt is shown below.

```
ClearAll[BubbleDown];
SetAttributes[BubbleDown, HoldFirst]; 
BubbleDown[H_, i_] := Module[{k, j, v, n = Length[H], heap},
  k = i; v = H[[k]]; heap = False;
  While[! heap && 2*k <= n,
   j = 2*k;
   If[j < n, If[H[[j]] < H[[j + 1]], j++]];
   If[v >= H[[j]], heap = True, H[[k]] = H[[j]]; k = j];
   ];
  H[[k]] = v]

ClearAll[HeapBottomUp];
SetAttributes[HeapBottomUp, HoldFirst];
HeapBottomUp[H_] := Module[{i, n = Length[H]},
  For[i = Floor[n/2], i >= 1, i--,
   BubbleDown[H, i]];
  H
  ]

ClearAll[HeapSort];
SetAttributes[HeapSort, HoldFirst];
HeapSort[H_] := Module[{n = Length[H], T = H, i},
  H = HeapBottomUp[H];
  For[i = n, i >= 2, i--,
   T[[i]] = H[[1]];
   H[[{1, i}]] = H[[{i, 1}]];
   H = H[[;; i - 1]];
   BubbleDown[H, 1]
   ];
  T
  ]
```

My main problem is that I do not want to use the local variable `T` in the `HeapSort` function. When I tried `BubbleDown[H[[;;I-1]]`, it did not work because of the HoldFirst setting for the function.

Is there a way to address this in order to make my implementation in place (space complexity of O(1))?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you wouldn't want to use the built in one https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/HeapSort.html?

Comment: I am trying to implement all the algorithms (listed in pseudocode) in Levitin's Algorithms book. So, I know, for example, that we have to avoid procedural programming, but I want to implement the algorithms in exactly the way described in the book.

Comment: Heapsort works by first queuing elements in a heap and then dequeuing them. It is difficult to see where your code is doing that. Which makes it difficult to offer advice. On a general note, it one wants to use `Hold*` attributes and operate on only a part of the object, functions such as `HeapBottomUp` should accept an index argument and use that to determine where to operate. That way copies are avoided (and they would mess up the algorithm complexity).

Comment: Many thanks, Daniel! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

As of V12.1, the [`"PriorityQueue"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/PriorityQueue.html) [data structure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html) is built in:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 40];

ds = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue", data];

Table[ds["Pop"], ds["Length"]]
```

> ```
> {990, 989, 981, 965, 862, 838, 835, 826, 813, 780, 772, 726, 715,
>  647, 630, 613, 556, 543, 536, 487, 399, 395, 385, 365, 325, 278,
>  276, 228, 179, 173, 147, 125, 97, 88, 70, 68, 29, 8, 5, 3}
> ```

We can use a custom ordering function to sort in ascending order:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue", data, Order[Minus[#1], Minus[#2]]&];

Table[ds["Pop"], ds["Length"]]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 8, 29, 68, 70, 88, 97, 125, 147, 173, 179, 228, 276, 278,
>  325, 365, 385, 395, 399, 487, 536, 543, 556, 613, 630, 647, 715,
>  726, 772, 780, 813, 826, 835, 838, 862, 965, 981, 989, 990}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your answer. However, as I mentioned in my other comment, I want to avoid using built-in data structures and implement the pseudocode of the HeapSort as in Levitin's book.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks go for Daniel for helping me to fix my problem. The fixed code is shown below:

```
ClearAll[BubbleDown];
SetAttributes[BubbleDown, HoldFirst]; 
BubbleDown[H_, n_, i_] := Module[{k, j, v, heap},
  k = i; v = H[[k]]; heap = False;
  While[! heap && 2*k <= n,
   j = 2*k;
   If[j < n, If[H[[j]] < H[[j + 1]], j++]];
   If[v >= H[[j]], heap = True, H[[k]] = H[[j]]; k = j];
   ];
  H[[k]] = v]

ClearAll[HeapBottomUp];
SetAttributes[HeapBottomUp, HoldFirst];
HeapBottomUp[H_] := Module[{i, n = Length[H]},
  For[i = Floor[n/2], i >= 1, i--,
   BubbleDown[H, n, i]];
  H
  ]

ClearAll[HeapSort];
SetAttributes[HeapSort, HoldFirst];
HeapSort[H_] := Module[{n = Length[H], i},
  H = HeapBottomUp[H];
  For[i = n, i >= 2, i--,
   H[[{1, i}]] = H[[{i, 1}]];
   BubbleDown[H, i - 1, 1]
   ];
  H
  ]
```